# Greater than and less than in my sql

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

I need to fetch the data from 2016-01-19 to 2016-01-21,including the date also.So i use the query like this

```
"SELECT * FROM events WHERE start_date <= '2016-01-21%' AND start_date >= '2016-01-19%'"
```

But i got only 2016-01-19,2016-01-20 data,not 2016-01-21.If there is any mistake in that query.please share the answer.

Comment: Use `between` keyword for mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first please make sure database **filed type** of "start_date" is **datetime** also we need to format date time to date

the try running this

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE ( DATE_FORMAT( start_date,  '%Y-%m-%d' ) >= '2016-01-19' AND DATE_FORMAT( start_date,  '%Y-%m-%d' ) <= '2016-01-21' )
```

Comment: Datatype of start_date is datetime.I used ur query but it returns same as my query.

Comment: it returns only 19 and 20 data only,not showing 21 data

Comment: can you please tick this answer as correct ,there is a tick mark

Answer (score 2):

Use [between](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp)

```
SELECT * 
FROM events 
WHERE start_date BETWEEN date(2016-01-21 00:00:00) AND date(2016-01-19 23:59:59);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`between`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-between-clause.htm) with [`date`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date.asp) function

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE start_date BETWEEN date(2016-01-21) AND date(2016-01-19)
                                          ^          ^                   ^
```

Comment: @Abdulla `;` is not required in `PHP`

Comment: In my database  start_date is in (2016-01-21 04:00:00) this format so i use (2016-01-21%).using this how to write a query

Comment: using like operator how to fech it

Comment: using like operator how to fetch it

Answer (score 0):

You may use BETWEEN , But keep in mind when using it the first date must be less then the second . Sorry for the first answers says the opposite .

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM events 
  WHERE start_date 
  BETWEEN  date(2016-01-19 00:00:00)
  AND   date(2016-01-21 23:59:59)
```